# Module 'tripSee' is not available when angular is included in the header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird issue that seems to be a problem with the order that I load angular compared to where I define my module. My page looks like so:

Header
Page

The header look like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tripSee">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<title></title>
```

The page looks like:

```
<body>
    stuff stuff stuff

    <script>
       (function(){

            var app = angular.module('tripSee', []);

            app.controller('TripController', function(){
                this.name = "Ray";
            });

       })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This throws an error like this:

Module 'tripSee' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

But if instead I move the angular.js include into the body area then this error goes away. I don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's timing of async versus sync script loading. I believe the Angular reference will load asynchronously while your embedded script defining the module will be run synchronously as the page HTML is loaded and parsed. It is generally best practice to put your JavaScript in separate files instead of embedding it, doing so would solve your timing problem.